# How to place HTML objects inside a mobile container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to place an image of mobile inside my webpage and i want to show all contents inside that mobile.for practical demostration,please have a look on http://goratchet.com/components/
and please tell me how it can be done.
[Live Demo](http://goratchet.com/components/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/nwmbm21f/

HTML:

```
<div class="device" style="" id="barsInDevice" style="background-color:Lime;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.device {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 395px;
    height: 813px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    background-image: url(http://goratchet.com/assets/img/device-sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-size: 300%;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-image .1s linear;
    transition: background-image .1s linear;
}
```

You need only to add the content you need inside the boundaries of the image.

Comment: it's not working.i have put some contents in div tag,content goes outside of the mobile.then i put some contents in body tag.same happens as well.any suggestion?

Comment: This is based on the div "device" element. Each element you want to put in there must be valid to the DOM of the page you are rendering, so you cant add a <body/> tag inside there.

Here's a quick guide to DOM Tree in HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp